# Data type differences between PHP sqlsrv driver and PDO driver

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, binary, sqlsrv

Here I am using `sqlsrv`:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect("192.168.1.102,1433", array("Database"=>"RF_User", "UID"=>"rfo-gcp", "PWD" => ""));

$tsql = "SELECT birthdate FROM tbl_rfaccount WHERE id = ?";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, array("test"));

$result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);

var_dump($result);
```

Result: `array(2) { [0]=> object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-04-19 20:40:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } ["birthdate"]=> object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-04-19 20:40:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } }`

Here I am using `PDO`:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.102,1433; Database=RF_User;", "rfo-gcp", "");

$tsql = "SELECT birthdate FROM tbl_rfaccount WHERE id = cast(? as varchar(13))";     

$stmt = $conn->prepare($tsql);

$stmt->execute(array("test"));

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```

Result: `array(1) { ["birthdate"]=> string(19) "2020-04-19 20:40:00" }`

If you notice, I had to use `cast(? as varchar(13))` on the `PDO` code. Without it would not return any row. On the `sqlsrv` I didn't have to use the `CAST()` function. Why is this? Also, **the `id` column on the database is a `BINARY(13)`**, so why do I have to cast the `id` to `varchar` and not to `binary` (with binary cast it also doesn't find the row)?

Comment: You should have cast that in the array for the bind instead of casting the placeholder.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How so? This is what I understood but it's probably not what you mean: `$stmt->execute(array("cast('test' as varchar(13))"));`

Comment: The `?` is a placeholder, not a value so it doesn't make sense that you would cast the placeholder. But casting the value as a column type (VARCHAR) just doesn't make sense at all as the value is either a number, string or boolean. In this case the value `text` is just a string. What error do you get if you don't perform this casting? What is the column type of `id` and is `test` an appropriate value for that column and type?

Comment: @JayBlanchard The column type is `BINARY(13)` (old database, can't change that). If I don't perform the casting there is no error, it just doesn't find the record when it should.

Comment: If the column type is binary then why try to select from that column with a text value? I think this is where the disconnect is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why date and time values are returned differently?**

In fact, this is only a setting.

When you use **PDO_SQLSRV** (as is [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-datetime-objects-using-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) in the documentation), *date and time types (smalldatetime, datetime, date, time, datetime2, and datetimeoffset) are by default returned as strings. Neither the PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES nor the PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE attribute has any effect. In order to retrieve date and time types as PHP DateTime objects, set the connection or statement attribute PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_DATETIME_TYPE to true (it is false by default)*.

When you use **SQLSRV** driver (again from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-date-and-time-type-as-strings-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15)), *smalldatetime, datetime, date, time, datetime2, and datetimeoffset types will be returned as PHP DateTime objects*. This behaviour can be changed by setting the `'ReturnDatesAsStrings'` option in the connection string or at the statement level.

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect(
   "192.168.1.102,1433", 
    array(
       "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true,
       "Database"=>"RF_User", 
       "UID"=>"rfo-gcp", 
       "PWD" => ""
   )
);
```

Note that some of the features depend on the version of PHP Driver for SQL Server.

**How to cast parameters values?**

Using `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` functions in the statement and binding parameter value with string value should work. Of course, you can specify the parameter data type, when you bind a parameter.

For **PDO_SQLSRV** you should extended syntax for [PDOStatement::bindParam()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-bindparam?view=sql-server-ver15).

For **SQLSRV** you may use the extended `$params` [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-specify-sql-server-data-types-when-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) to specify the SQL Server data type, when you make a call to `sqlsrv_query()\sqlsrv_execute()`.

I'm able to reproduce this issue (PHP 7.1.12, PHP Driver for SQL Server 4.3.0+9904, SQL Server 2012) and the solution is to use:

```
$params = array($id, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BINARY);          // SQLSRV
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_LOB, null, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY); // PDO_SQLSRV
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_rfaccount (id binary(13), birthdate datetime)
INSERT INTO tbl_rfaccount (id, birthdate) VALUES (CONVERT(binary(13), 'Test'), GETDATE())
```

PHP:

```
<?php
...

// 
$id = "Test";

// SQLSRV
$tsql = "SELECT birthdate FROM tbl_rfaccount WHERE id = ?";
$params = array($id, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BINARY);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
$result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);

// PDO_SQLSRV
$tsql = "SELECT birthdate FROM tbl_rfaccount WHERE id = ?";     
$stmt = $conn->prepare($tsql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_LOB, null, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);

...
?>
```

Comment: I was already aware of the reason why date/time values are returned differently but thank you for clarifying that. The problem here is casting the values to the proper data type. While SQLSRV has the data type `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BINARY`, PDO_SQLSRV does not. I am stuck using PDO and I am lost as to how I am going to accomplish this.

Comment: @DanVeira I think you should use the correct parameter binding. Please, see the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: WOW @Zhorov! Excellent explanation! I rarely use SQL server anymore, but this sheds some light on some issues I have encountered when doing so.

Comment: @Zhorov That works! SQLSRV (without PDO) seems like the superior driver in regards to data types. Also, are you familiar with Laravel? Any idea how to pass those driver options to its query builder? Thank you!

Comment: @DanVeira Glad to help! And no, I have no experience with Laravel.