# No data from Database

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I wrote an php application which should select data from the database depending on a given date. The date in the Database is stored like `2020-07-03`. The code which executes the statement looks like

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Database WHERE Date < $from";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if($stmt == false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
echo $sql;

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
    echo $row[0].", ".$row[1]."<br />";
}
```

`$from` and `$to` is a range which is given by the user with date-input fields and return the userinput like `2020-07-02`. The datatype of the field "Date" is Date. I do not get any error or something similar but it won't execute the while loop and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Don't inject your parameters, use a parametrised/prepared query. `WHERE Date < $from` will result in `WHERE Date < 2020-07-03` which would be `WHERE Date < 2010`. As a `datetime` the `int` value `2010` is the value `'1905-07-04'`, which I doubt you have any rows with a value less than that.

Comment: Shouldn't the date be quoted to work with a direct variable? `WHERE Date < '$from'`? Even better, use a prepared statement - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php -- that way, you don't have to worry about it being quoted or not, and its an additional layer of security.

Comment: No should be parametrised, @Qirel , not injected with quotes.

Comment: @Larnu Read my full comment....

Comment: YOu edited that in *After* I made my comment, @Qirel ...

Comment: Allowing user input directly in your SQL like that is like asking for someone to do injection attacks to dump your SQL server credentials etc.... Dangerous...

Comment: @Qirel: Tried it with prepared statement but still no difference. It won't execute the while-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parameters in your statement. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), `sqlsrv_query()` *function is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply. This function provides a streamlined method to execute a query with a minimum amount of code. The sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries*.

You need to pass the values of parameters in one of the following ways:

- As text using an unambiguous date format (`yyyymmdd`),
- Using extended parameters syntax and the appropriate data type bindings.

Example, based on the code in the question, using text values for dates:

```
<?php
// Connection
$server    = 'server,port';
$database  = 'database';
$uid       = 'uid';
$pwd       = 'pwd';
$cinfo = array(
   "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true,
   "Database" => $database,
   "UID" => $uid,
   "PWD" => $pwd
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
   echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
   exit;
}

// Test input
$from = (new DateTime('2020-07-02'))->format('Ymd');
$to   = (new DateTime('2020-07-03'))->format('Ymd');

// Statement
$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM Database 
    WHERE (? <= [Date]) AND ([Date] <= ?)"
;
$params = array($from, $to);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if($stmt == false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
echo $sql;

// Data
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
    echo $row[0].", ".$row[1]."<br />";
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

?>
```

Example, based on the code in the question, using PHP date objects and the appropriate parameters bindings:

```
<?php
// Connection
$server    = 'server,port';
$database  = 'database';
$uid       = 'uid';
$pwd       = 'pwd';
$cinfo = array(
   "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true,
   "Database" => $database,
   "UID" => $uid,
   "PWD" => $pwd
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
   echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
   exit;
}

// Test input
$from = new DateTime('2020-07-02');
$to   = new DateTime('2020-07-03');

// Statement
$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM Database 
    WHERE (CONVERT(date, ?) <= [Date]) AND ([Date] <= CONVERT(date, ?))"
;
$params = array(
   array($from, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_DATETIME, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME),
   array($to, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_DATETIME, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME)
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if($stmt == false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
echo $sql;

// Data
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
    echo $row[0].", ".$row[1]."<br />";
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

?>
```

Comment: Got the following error now ``Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string``

Comment: Got another error. ``core_sqlsrv_bind_param: invalid encoding`` and it says it would occur on this line ``$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params); ``

Comment: @fhprogrammer The example in the answer works correctly (tested with PHP 7.4.8 and PHP Driver for SQL Server 5.8). I'm able to reproduce the second error if I use `$from = (new DateTime('2020-07-02'))->format('Ymd')` instead of `$from = new DateTime('2001-07-02')` in the second example. Thanks.

Comment: in my case It doesn't neither the first example nor the second one. When I try the first one I get the first error, when I try the second one I get the second error message. I'm sorry

Comment: @fhprogrammer 1) For the first example - check how exactly you fetch date values returned from the statement (this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350489/data-type-differences-between-php-sqlsrv-driver-and-pdo-driver/61352482#61352482) explains a similar issue). 2) For the second example you need to assign PHP datetime objects to the `$from` and `$to` variables, not strings. The examples are updated with the `"ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true,` connection option.