# MSSQL Returns date and time columns in weird formats

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I have a model called overtime with the columns date, start and end.
I'm using mssql.

Date is stored in the database as "date" type with the value 2019-12-16.
Start and end is stored as "time(7)" with the values 07:00:00.0000000 and 08:00:00.0000000

When I use a raw query like this

```php
    dd(DB::table('overtimes')->limit(1)->get());
```

The column values are returned like this

```php
Date: Dec 16 2019 12:00:00:AM
Start: Jan  1 1900 07:00:00:0000000AM
End: Jan  1 1900 08:00:00:0000000AM
```

I just want them in normal formats like this:
Date as 2019-12-16
Start as 07:00:00.000
End as 08:00:00.000

Is this a problem with mssql setup maybe?

**EDIT**
I tried setting these options in the database.php config file

```php
'options' => [
  'returnDatesAsStrings' => true,
  PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => true
],
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: How the values are *displayed* has nothing to do with SQL Server. Date and Time data types are stored as binary values. If you need to display the value in a certain format that something your application/presentation layer needs to define.

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350489/data-type-differences-between-php-sqlsrv-driver-and-pdo-driver/61352482#61352482). My guess is that you are using `sqlsrv` driver to connect to SQL Server, so use the appropriate PDO option.

Comment: What do you mean by `mssql` - MS SQL Server or the `mssql` PHP extension?

Comment: I mean MS SQL Server

Comment: @J.Doe `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_DATETIME_TYPE => true` (but PHP Driver for SQL Server 5.6 is needed) will return date/time values as PHP DateTime objects and you can easily format them as you expect using PHP `DateTime::format` method.

Comment: Since you tagged laravel, you should be using Eloquent for this, so your model can do casting automatically. `Overtime::first();`